# How can $n$-dimensional space be projected?

Tags: geometry, visualization

How is spacial projection generalized? For example I can project three-dimensional space into two-dimensional space (like with a camera), I can project two dimensional space into a dotted line or something. I can't manage to fathom how $n$-dimensional space is projected into a form my mind can understand. How is this type of projection generalized for use with an ambiguously defined number of spacial dimensions?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start (and stop) at 4D, because even that is tricky.

[image]

A face of a 4D cube is a 3D cube and each 4D cube has 8 such faces. The picture above shows a 4D cube projected into a plane with the four principal, orthogonal axes shown. It takes a lot of staring to see the faces of a 4D cube. The pictures below try to illustrate how the two faces along each of the four axes are situated in 4D.

[image]

> I can't manage to fathom how n-dimensional space is projected into a form my mind can understand.

Nobody else can either, working in 4D is difficult enough

> How is this type of projection generalized for use with an ambiguously defined number of spacial dimensions?

It's not. We use math instead and totally give up on the "try to visualise"  idea. Your brain is hardwired for 3D, so it's impossible.

Comment: It may not be visualization, but people have certainly come up with tricks for understanding how things behave in higher dimensions. This usually works by first imagining how someone restricted to 1 or 2 dimensions would try to visualize three dimensional space and then using analogous techniques to understand dimensions higher than 3. Maybe the first example to try is understanding why two planes which meet at a point in 5 dimensions can be perturbed slightly so they don't intersect (understand why this works for lines in 3 dimensions first). Whether or not this is useful is another question.

Comment: @SeanPohorence one math based pop sci book by Rudy Rucker says that in 15 years of trying, he had been able to see in 4D for a total of 15 minutes, and that it scared him, because of  the  unreality, enough to stop trying.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a D-dimensional vector $\vec{d} \in \mathbb{R}^D$ you can project that vector into a (D-1)-dimensional [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) perpendicular to a unit-vector $\vec{n}$ in the following way:

The component of $\vec{d}$ along the direction of $\vec{n}$ is its projection
$$ d_n = \vec{n} \cdot \vec{d} $$

So the part of $\vec{d}$ pointing along $\vec{n}$ is
$$ \vec{d_n} = d_n \cdot \vec{n} $$

The part of $\vec{d}$ perpendicular to $\vec{n}$ is therefore:
$$ \vec{d}_\perp = \vec{d} - \vec{d_n} $$
since $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{d}_\perp =  \vec{n} \cdot \vec{d} - \vec{n} \cdot \vec{d_n} = d_n - d_n = 0$.

Thus we define the projection function $P_{\vec{n}}: \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow H_\vec{n} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{D-1}$ by
$$ P_{\vec{n}}(\vec{x}) = \vec{x} - (\vec{n}\cdot\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{n} $$
which projects every vector into the hyperplane $H_\vec{n} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{D-1}$ perpendicular to $\vec{n}$.

For $D=3$ this would be a (rotated) plane, where $\vec{n}$ is the plane's normal vector.
For $D=4$ this would be a (4-dimensional rotated) 3-dimensional space, etc.